# Hide div if user signed in

Tags: jquery

I am working with Vanilla and want to hide a div if the user is signed in.

One of the coders gave me this code.

```
<script language="javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 if (gdn.definition('SignedIn', '0') != '0') {
 <div class="sp-container">
   <p>blah blah blah</p>
 </div>
 }
 });
 </script>
```

The div class sp-container I want to hide IF user is signed in.

One of the members suggested, using

```
    $('.sp-container').hide();
```

or

```
    $('.sp-container').css({'visibility':'hidden'});
```

But I am not sure how to actually do that code. Or where and how to add it... any help please.

All I wish to do is, NOT display the div sp-container IF user is signed in.

Comment: hold on - what's the question? Hide it if they ARE signed in, hide it UNLESS they are signed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will work as dont know vanilla - but this will work if the property is set :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (gdn.definition('SignedIn', '0') != '0') {
       jQuery(".sp-container").hide();
    }
 });
 </script>
```

This will run after the DOM is ready (the `ready()` function) and will check the `gdn.definition` - if its not '0' it will hide the div with the class "sp-container" - remember to include the jQuery library

Answer (score 1):

Put the first line (the hide) immediately before the }); at the end.

If they're not logged in then the hide won't find the div and it won't matter anyway.

On the other hand - you could just remove the whole thing completely and nothing will appear, logged in or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you need, but pretty close.
Inside your script tags which can be either in the head of your document (in which case document.ready would be required, or near the footer (which a lot of people do so the javascript loads after the page does).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// use the document.ready to process the if statement only after the page completely loads
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // hide the container if the user is logged in
    if (gdn.definition('SignedIn', '0') != '0') {
         jQuery('div.sp-container').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Then you can include the sp-container div in your page and it will be hidden if you are signed in.

Also note that language="javascript" is deprecated; type="text/javascript" should be used in your script tags instead, unless you're using a pretty old document header.

Also, if the only javascript library you have included is jQuery, you can substitute simply using "$" instead of "jQuery". (e.g. $('div.sp-container').hide();)